# Square REST API: Error issuing refund

Tags: square, square-connect

Every time I try to refund a card, I get the JSON pasted below. This happens after I authorize a card, then capture the charge, then want to issue a partial refund. For “tender_id” I have tried both the transaction ID and the ID I am handed during the authorization. Of course for the capture there is no tender_id or id because a successful capture returns just “{}”.

I am also using sandbox credentials. The charge was done with a nonce generated with sandbox credentials as well.

What’s wrong?

Thanks...

POST to:

```
 https://connect.squareup.com/v2/locations/CBASEHHNorL75TjuSOAvKQLnuNYgAQ/transactions/a2905f34-c8e8-5534-7676-82e8c580e9bf/refund
```

With this JSON:

```
 {  
    "idempotency_key":"6464dc19-1703-47c0-81f9-4f0f1361eada",
    "tender_id":"291d56b3-1e73-5bff-6e8e-719fd134b83f",
    "reason":”Partial refund",
    "amount_money":{  
       "amount":4500,
       "currency":"USD"
   }
 }
```

Gives this reply:

```
 {
   "errors": [
     {
       "category": "INVALID_REQUEST_ERROR",
       "code": "NOT_FOUND",
       "detail": "Location `CBASEHHNorL75TjuSOAvKQLnuNYgAQ` does not have a transaction tender with ID `291d56b3-1e73-5bff-6e8e-719fd134b83f`."
     }
   ]
 }
```

UPDATE: The result from the requested GET call (in the comments to the answer) is:

```
 {  
    "transaction":{  
  "id":"a2905f34-c8e8-5534-7676-82e8c580e9bf",
  "location_id":"CBASEHHNorL75TjuSOAvKQLnuNYgAQ",
  "created_at":"2017-02-21T22:08:10Z",
  "tenders":[  
     {  
        "id":"a18b98c7-5ac7-51c1-618c-3b95ee124c1b",
        "location_id":"CBASEHHNorL75TjuSOAvKQLnuNYgAQ",
        "transaction_id":"a2905f34-c8e8-5534-7676-82e8c580e9bf",
        "created_at":"2017-02-21T22:08:10Z",
        "note":"Online Transaction",
        "amount_money":{  
           "amount":12500,
           "currency":"USD"
        },
        "processing_fee_money":{  
           "amount":372,
           "currency":"USD"
        },
        "type":"CARD",
        "card_details":{  
           "status":"CAPTURED",
           "card":{  
              "card_brand":"VISA",
              "last_4":"5858"
           },
           "entry_method":"KEYED"
        }
     }
  ],
  "reference_id":"63614ae8-539a-4339-b5c7-554bae64fbed",
  "product":"EXTERNAL_API"
    }
 }
```

Comment: usually a refund can take place only after a given time period after the original transaction was done. When was this card charged? try refund on a card charged yesterday.

Comment: I actually thought of that, but nothing in the docs says this is the case. If it is the case, and the required delay is more than several minutes, I'll have a problem.

Comment: The only time limit is the timing of the network connections to our systems. You should be able to refund almost instantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you capture, have you tried listing/retrieving the transaction to get the full details, including tender ids? Could you post your response from `GET /v2/locations/CBASEHHNorL75TjuSOAvKQLnuNYgAQ/transactions/a2905f34-c8e8-5534-7676-82e8c580e9bf` if that doesn't work?

Comment: I'll try that, thanks. But why should that be necessary? The authorization gives me several IDs (I don't understand the different purposes of each). The response to the charge with capture false is a list of tenders, each of which has an id. Why should that returned ID not be valid?

Comment: Okay @tristansokol I tried it again, from scratch. Created an authorization, captured it, listed the transactions to verify it is there. It was and it had the same transaction id as the auth id I got when I authorized. I tried to refund it. Same error. I tried the id and the tender_id. Also tried a charge I made several days ago. All with the same error. Can you please escalate this?

Comment: You don't have to, but you aren't capturing the tender Id properly, those steps were to help you debug. You need to use the `tender_id` (`a18b98c7-5ac7-51c1-618c-3b95ee124c1b`) in your refund request JSON. In your post body above you used the `transaction_id` of a different transaction. Happy to explain how tenders and transactions are different if that would help.

Comment: I just tried doing a charge without delayed capture to see if that would allow me to issue a refund. Same error exactly.

Comment: Again, It appears that you tried to use a transaction id `ad51e03e-c287-5905..` instead of the tender id `242be5cc-2d2e-5563-5531-42dc920c24ec`

Comment: Thanks, but I actually did try it with both. So, when I do a charge I get a list of tenders. Fields in the tender include "id" and "transaction_id". I have tried both of these. When I do, I put it both into the uri and the JSON body. Another point of confusion is that the value of the id field from the tender match the value of the id field of the transaction itself. That implies that this field is used to link any particular tender to the transaction, since there could be more than one tender. This is why I thought I should use the transaction_id from the tender. Still, neither works for me.

Comment: Don't put the `tender_id` in the URI. If you wanted to refund part of transaction `ad51e03e-c287-5905-6bfc-24cade8a6ed1` You would send the request to `https://connect.squareup.com/v2/locations/CBASEHHNorL75TjuSOAvKQLnuNYgAQ/transactions/ad51e03e-c287-5905-6bfc-24cade8a6ed1f/refund` with the `tender_id` in the body (`242be5cc-2d2e-5563-5531-42dc920c24ec`)

Comment: Ah ha! That got it thanks! Is there a doc that explains what a tender is and what the three different IDs are? I'm not clear on why we have a list of tenders. Also, which of these IDs will I need in the future, for example if I need to reference a transaction, or refund it, or whatever? I'm asking what I need to put into my database. Thank you!

Comment: Tender ids are different than transactions, because a single transaction could have multiple tenders (ie, paying with cash and card) . You can get all the information using the transaction id and the retrieve endpoint, so keep that!